# IE 9 and JQuery - IE9 only displays first character

Tags: jquery, regex, internet-explorer, jquery-inputmask

I have the jQuery below on my pages and they work fine in Chrome but when I view in IE9 i only get the first character displayed.  What am I missing?

```
$(".alpha").inputmask('Regex', { regex: "[a-zA-Z ]+" }); // Limits entry to letters and space character
$(".name").inputmask('Regex', { regex: "[a-zA-Z-`' ]+" }); // Limits entry to letters, -, `, ' and space character 
$(".alphanumeric").inputmask('Regex', { regex: "[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" }); // Limits entry to letters, numbers and space character
```

Comment: Can you link to an actual demo, please?

Comment: I found out why the jquery is not working.  For some reason the page is loading in IE9 compatibility mode.  When I switch to IE 9 standard mode it works fine.  Not sure why the page load in compat mode everytime though

Comment: Do you start your document with `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Comment: Yes I do.  Is that the only thing that will send IE into compat. mode?

Comment: Adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> to the head fixes it but this must be a hack huh.  I must have something wrong somewhaere else to cause this

Comment: You don't want to do that; that will disable a lot of features in modern browsers. Which document/browser modes have (Default) next to them? Also, is this on a particular domain?

Comment: @Johnathan Sampson when I remove the meta tag, dev tools only has a default next to Document Mode IE 9 Standards, however, it initially loads (check next to them) with browser mode: IE 9 compatibility and document mode: IE 7 standards

Comment: If it has (Default) next to IE 9 Standards, then just select that option. What it's doing is telling you what the Browser wants to do (IE 9 Standards), but respecting a user-override (IE 7 Standards). Your users shouldn't have the same issue when viewing your website, unless they have overridden their settings too.

Comment: @JonathanSampson when I view another webpage like cnn.com, the page loads with IE9 Standards, it is only when I view this one website that it always loads with IE7 Standards.  Can this be triggered due to something in my markup for this website?

Comment: Having no doctype, or an invalid doctype, can cause that. Instructing the document to be in IE7 mode via an `x-ua-compat` meta tag or header would do it too. Otherwise, the only way to trigger IE7 mode would be by a Compat List (managed by Microsoft), or by manually setting your browser into IE7 mode via F12 Developer Tools. What is the domain?

Comment: @JonathanSampson it is on a local development web server

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43792/discussion-between-jonathan-sampson-and-jason)

Comment: @JonathanSampson When I test the site on my local workstation IE loads it as it should.  It is only loading IE 7 standard and IE 9 compat mode when loaded from the dev server.  They must have configured the dev server to do that huh?  If will have to talk with them.